# How to use RESTEasy client framework to send data in a POST

Tags: java, rest, resteasy

I am using the RESTEasy client framework to call a RESTful webservice.  The call is made via a POST and sends some XML data to the server.  How do I accomplish this?

What is the magical incantation of annotations to use to make this happen?

Comment: @David Escandell, would you please post the entire example here. I am able to post the data using xml but not able to serialize the object properly. I hope your example can help me a lot.

Comment: I love the "magical incantation of annotations" part of the question ... it is one of the great parts of this new engineering phenomena!

Answer (score 13):

I think David is referring to the RESTeasy "Client Framework". Therefore, your answer (Riduidel) is not particularly what he is looking for. Your solution uses HttpUrlConnection as the http client. Using the resteasy client instead of HttpUrlConnection or DefaultHttpClient is beneficial because resteasy client is JAX-RS aware. To use the RESTeasy client, you construct org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientRequest objects and build up requests using its constructors and methods. Below is how I'd implement David's question using the client framework from RESTeasy.

```
ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest("http://url/resource/{id}");

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("<user id=\"0\">");
sb.append("   <username>Test User</username>");
sb.append("   <email>test.user@test.com</email>");
sb.append("</user>");


String xmltext = sb.toString();

request.accept("application/xml").pathParameter("id", 1).body( MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, xmltext);

String response = request.postTarget( String.class); //get response and automatically unmarshall to a string.

//or

ClientResponse<String> response = request.post();
```

Hope this helps,
Charlie

Comment: That does indeed help.

The solution I found was even simpler.  The framework allows you to build a java interface defining the REST methods you are going to call.  you can place a @Produces("application/xml") in front of the method, then pass in objects with appropriate JAXB annotations, and everything magically works.

Comment: Definitely! That way of making the calls uses RESTeasy Client Proxies. You could call it another kind of "client framework" for making restful services. I even prefer this method because it allows you to reuse the service interface from the server also on the client and thus, have an easier self-documenting and unified api.

Answer (score 5):

It is as easy as following

```
    @Test
    public void testPost() throws Exception {
        final ClientRequest clientCreateRequest = new ClientRequest("http://localhost:9090/variables");
        final MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParameters = clientCreateRequest.getFormParameters();
        final String name = "postVariable";
        formParameters.putSingle("name", name);
        formParameters.putSingle("type", "String");
        formParameters.putSingle("units", "units");
        formParameters.putSingle("description", "description");
        formParameters.putSingle("core", "true");
        final ClientResponse<String> clientCreateResponse = clientCreateRequest.post(String.class);
        assertEquals(201, clientCreateResponse.getStatus());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this syntax:

```
Form form = new Form();
form
 .param("client_id", "Test_Client")
 .param("grant_type", "password")
 .param("response_type", "code")
 .param("scope", "openid")
 .param("redirect_uri", "some_redirect_url");
Entity<Form> entity = Entity.form(form);
    
ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/auth/realms");
Response response = target
 .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authCreds)
 .post(entity);

System.out.println("HTTP code: " + response.getStatus());
```

Comment: i try this for a kettle service but is givin me 302

Answer (score 1):

I had some trouble figuring out how to do this so I thought I would post it here. Using the RESTeasy proxy client mechanism is actually embarrassingly easy.

As Charles Akalugwu suggests, this approach allows you to create a single Java interface which you can use on both the client and server side, and results in both client- and server-side code that's obvious and easy to use.

First, declare a Java interface for the service. This will be used on both the client and server side, and should contain all of the JAX-RS declarations:

```
@Path("/path/to/service")
public interface UploadService
{
  @POST
  @Consumes("text/plan")
  public Response uploadFile(InputStream inputStream);
}
```

Next, write a server which implements this interface. It's as easy as it looks:

```
public class UploadServer extends Application implements UploadService
{
  @Override
  public Response uploadFile(InputStream inputStream)
  {
    // The inputStream contains the POST data
    InputStream.read(...);

    // Return the location of the new resource to the client:
    Response.created(new URI(location)).build();
  }
}
```

To answer the question "how to use RESTEasy Client Framework to send data in a POST", all you have to do is call the service interface from the client side via a RESTeasy proxy, and RESTeasy will do the POST for you. To create the client proxy:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target("http://path/to/service");
ResteasyWebTarget rtarget = (ResteasyWebTarget)target;
UploadService uploadService = rtarget.proxy(UploadService.class);
```

To POST data to the service:

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("/tmp/myfile");
uploadService.uploadFile(inputStream);
```

Naturally, if you are writing to an existing REST service then you could approach the problem by writing a Java interface just for the client.

Answer (score 0):

I borrowed from this example : [Build restful service with RESTEasy](http://jeff.familyyu.net/2009/08/build-restful-service-with-resteasy.html) the following code fragment, which seems to do exactly what you want, no ?

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8081/user");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);

StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer();
sbuffer.append("<user id=\"0\">");
sbuffer.append("   <username>Test User</username>");
sbuffer.append("   <email>test.user@test.com</email>");
sbuffer.append("</user>");

OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
os.write(sbuffer.toString().getBytes());
os.flush();

assertEquals(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED, connection.getResponseCode());
connection.disconnect();
```